# Фоновые синхронные задачи

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, fastapi

Почему фоновые таски не асинхронные? [Пример](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/)

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


def write_notification(email: str, message=""):
    with open("log.txt", mode="w") as email_file:
        content = f"notification for {email}: {message}"
        email_file.write(content)


@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, email, message="some notification")
    return {"message": "Notification sent in the background"}
```

В примере выше есть задача, которая является синхронной функцией. Как фоновая задача может быть синхронной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[В исходниках видно](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/background.py), что fastapi, в зависимости от того: синхронная функция или нет, -- решает делать над ней декоратор или не делать его.

```
import asyncio
import typing

from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool


class BackgroundTask:
    def __init__(
        self, func: typing.Callable, *args: typing.Any, **kwargs: typing.Any
    ) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.is_async = asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func)

    async def __call__(self) -> None:
        if self.is_async:
            await self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        else:
            await run_in_threadpool(self.func, *self.args, **self.kwargs)


class BackgroundTasks(BackgroundTask):
    def __init__(self, tasks: typing.Sequence[BackgroundTask] = []):
        self.tasks = list(tasks)

    def add_task(
        self, func: typing.Callable, *args: typing.Any, **kwargs: typing.Any
    ) -> None:
        task = BackgroundTask(func, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tasks.append(task)

    async def __call__(self) -> None:
        for task in self.tasks:
            await task()
```